# How to create a network graph with nodes as users and links representing shared person(degree of users) between those users in python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, pycharm, networkx

I am having trouble creating a network graph with nodes as users and links between them having the degree of persons sharing the users. Example of a csv file containing nodes is in the image below, and the graph to be plotted is shown based on the example. [Image showing file containing nodes and graph showing users sharing same set of nodes as links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub1P4.jpg). I am having trouble understanding how to get the degree in the graph. This is my first time using networkx for creating a graph.

I don't know where to start. I tried creating a graph with nx.draw between the nodes but do not know how to add edges based on shared person.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible input? (Not an image)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), python sets, and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), then pass the tuples of weighted edges to [`add_weighted_edges_from`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_weighted_edges_from.html):

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import combinations 
from collections import Counter

l = [('U1', 'P1'),
     ('U1', 'P3'),
     ('U2', 'P1'),
     ('U2', 'P3'),
     ('U3', 'P3'),
     ('U3', 'P4'),
     ('U4', 'P5'),]

d = {}

for n, k in l:
    d.setdefault(k, set()).add(n)

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from([
    (*k, v) for k, v in
    Counter(x for s in d.values()
            for x in combinations(s, 2)
           ).items()
])
```

Weighted edges:

```
[('U1', 'U2', 2), ('U1', 'U3', 1), ('U3', 'U2', 1)]
```

##### plotting

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos=pos)
```

Output:

[image: networkx weighed graph edges plot]